# How to change the file version and product name of a .dll using C?

Tags: c, dll, versioning, getfileversion

when I click the properties of .Dll -> Details , I get this window:
[image]

I want to access this information and change \ add File version and Product Name
Can I get some help with it ? how can I access it ? 
I saw that in C# I can use :

```
string fileVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(file).FileVersion;
string productVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(file).ProductVersion;
```

but I want to do it using C language.

can anyone help and guide me a little?

thanks!

Comment: I'd be surprised if there is an API to change that info, so you probably have to edit the dll file contents as raw data. Is this what you want to do? Also, why C? Anyway, check docs of FileVersionInfo (google for link to msdn page) first.

Comment: I'm sorry - but what does it mean "as raw data" ? I saw the msdn and googled it , but I always get the functions of the getters, and I'm looking for the setters

Comment: Are you making your own dll, in other words you have source and project files? If so, my above comment is irrelevant, forget it. But if you have an existing dll without sources, then you need to change the dll file contents ("raw data").

Comment: I'm using a sample dll , I'm not the one creating it. is there a way I can access these contents?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version information is kept as resource files in Windows. You can check the source code of this [tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13355/Modification-of-Version-Information-Resources-in-C) for how to change the resource in a file.

Comment: And you could also provide an explicit API inside your library to get it, e.g. have a `const char* mylib_version_string(void);` function in it.

Comment: Providing an API to give version information is common practice, and it is operating system independent.